# How do you use the Solr 7.4 restore API with HDFS?

Tags: solr, hdfs, solrcloud, solrconfig, solr7

I'm using Solr 7.4 along with Hadoop 2.7.5. I have an existing Collection that I want to backup and restore. I was able to complete the backup with no issues, but now I want to test the restore API. I'm doing all this in a staging environment as a proof of concept as I will have to restore our production index onto a new server.

The main issue I'm running into is that I don't know if I'm using the restore API correctly. This is what I'm calling: http://localhost:8983/solr/MyNewTestCollection/replication?command=restore
Do I need to use the "repository" and "location" parameters in the API? My understanding was no since my solr.xml file states how to use HDFS to do the backup/restore.

In my solr.xml I have:

```
<backup>
  <repository name="hdfs" class="org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.HdfsBackupRepository" default="false">
    <str name="location">${solr.hdfs.default.backup.path}</str>
    <str name="solr.hdfs.home">${solr.hdfs.home:hdfs://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8020/user/solr}</str>
    <str name="solr.hdfs.confdir">${solr.hdfs.confdir:/etc/hadoop/conf}</str>
  </repository>
</backup>
```

Also, below is the ouput I get from calling the API:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/Collection4/replication. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        ... 12 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>`enter code here`

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you have more info in the applicative logs of Solr?

Comment: I did go through the Solr logs, but I wasn't able to find anything helpful. It mentioned that hdfs wasn't installed even though it was. I did end up getting it to work after playing with the API call for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is needing this information, here are the steps I took.

1. I added the  block to my solr.xml file as I initially mentioned above
2. I created the new collection using the Solr Admin UI
3. When creating the collection, I provided the existing configset to be used for the new collection by selecting it in the dropdown menu
4. I uploaded my snapshots that were created using the Solr backup API to the default backups path I've set in HDFS
5. I called the Solr restore API as follows: http://localhost:8983/solr/MyNewTestCollection/replication?command=restore&repository=hdfs&location=PathToBackupInHdfs&name=SnapshotName